# How to find the Edge ID between two vertices in Gremlin

Tags: graph, gremlin, gremlin-server

Suppose we have a graph **g** with many vertices and we need to find an edge and edge ID between vertices **v1** and vertices **v2** having ID **id1** and **id2**.

Answer (score 8):

The traversal for this is just:

```
g.V(id1).bothE().where(otherV().hasId(id2))
```

I used `bothE()` as you didn't say whether the edge would go from *v1* to *v2* or vice versa. When you know the direction already then you should use `outE()` or `inE()`. In addition to that, when you know the edge label then you should provide it to this step to reduce the number of edges to be traversed.

For TinkerPop's modern graph, this looks like this:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().valueMap(true)
==>[name:[marko],label:person,id:1,age:[29]]
==>[name:[vadas],label:person,id:2,age:[27]]
==>[name:[lop],label:software,id:3,lang:[java]]
==>[name:[josh],label:person,id:4,age:[32]]
==>[name:[ripple],label:software,id:5,lang:[java]]
==>[name:[peter],label:person,id:6,age:[35]]
gremlin> g.V(1).bothE().where(otherV().hasId(2)).id()
==>7
```

and optimized with explicit direction and edge label:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).outE('knows').where(inV().hasId(2)).id()
==>7
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using gremlin-python with orientDB below snippet will help you.

```
g.V(from_v_id).outE(label).where(__.inV().where(__.hasId("#" + to_v_id))).next()
```

Comment: Thank you for adding this. The documention on gremlin-python is pretty poor. It would be useful if others could add more on gremlin-python docs when you come across. For others, this might also be useful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gremlin-users

Comment: Here are some gremlin-python abstractions for others interested: https://gist.github.com/joshwolff1/b61748f9342a4a3ef597d3d3b72ef027